Intuition for why $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \delta(t) dt = f(0)$
What is a good, intuitive, 1st-year Calculus student, layman's-terms reason that the Dirac delta function $\delta(t)$ is defined to have the characteristic $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \delta(t) dt = f(0)$?
The best I've got right now is that since the integral really only takes place when t = 0 (because it's 0 everywhere else due to $\delta(t)$ being 0 everywhere else), and it appears that $\int_0^0 \delta (t) dt = 1$ (weird but I'll allow it), then $f(t) \delta(t)$ just scales $\delta(t)$ by $f(t)$ at the point when t = 0...aka it's just scaling by $f(0)$. Thus if $\int_0^0 \delta (t) dt = 1$, then it would make sense that multiplying this integral by the scalar $f(0)$ would just give the result $\int_0^0 f(0)\delta (t) dt = f(0)$, and thus (kinda) $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \delta(t) dt = f(0)$
Is my intuition acceptable? Or is there a better way to think about it?

Typos: you mean $f(0)$ not $1$ in the title (and also your first paragraph). Umm, I guess this is fine ‘intuition’, but really the Dirac delta does NOT belong under an integral as written in this manner no matter how much people write and say to the contrary. You should really just think of $\delta_a$ as a gadget which eats a function $f$ and spits out the number $f(a)$, so by definition, $\delta_a(f):=f(a)$. See here. This is so much cleaner as a definition, and also operationally: the definition does literally what we want.

Intuitively, imagine that the Dirac delta function $\delta$ is just a regular old smooth function which has a bump very near the origin and is zero outside the interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. The area under the curve is $1$. If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \delta(x) , dx = \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(x) \delta(x) , dx \approx  \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon f(0) \delta(x) , dx = f(0)  \int_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon \delta(x) , dx = f(0)$. This is the intuitive way of understanding the delta function.

I appreciate you both. Typos fixed!
I think the comment you left, littleO, is essentially my intuition, except I put 0 for the bounds instead of $\pm \epsilon$.
Cheers!

To add to peek-a-boo's comment: a normal function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ can also be seen as such a "gadget". It eats $f$ and spits out $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(t)dt$ (we have to put some conditions on $f$ and $g$ that the integral exists). In that sense, $\delta$ is a "generalized function" and these are also called "distributions". But it isn't a function and it's pointless to wonder how such a function can exist, because it doesn't.

Seems like I just need a bit more exposure to math. This whole "it's called a function but it isn't a function and it can't exist but we use it like it exists" is a bit confusing at the moment, but I think I'm grasping a bit more.

@peek-a-boo : There is a very good reason to write the Dirac delta in an integral: it can be identified with (or defined as) a measure $\delta_0(A) = 1$ iff $0\in A$. Then the associated integral constructed with respect to this measure is indeed, say for any $f$ continuous in $0$
$$
\int f(x),\delta_0(\mathrm d x) = f(0)
$$
where I used the notation $\int f(x),\mu(\mathrm d x)$ for the integral of $f$ with respect to a measure $\mu$.

@LL3.14 of course and I wasn’t objecting to the Dirac measure. What I was objecting to (as I vaguely alluded to in my caveat “…. as written in this manner”) is writing $\delta(t)$ (I know… OP said they’re only looking for an intuitive and lay-person’s intuition, so please excuse me being more pedantic) and treating it as the (non-existent) Radon-Nikodym derivative with respect to Lebesgue measure, because in my experience TAing students, this was the quickest recipe for confusion

I appreciate you both meeting me at the level of understanding I needed.

A personally better picture would be as follows:

We always fix a very, very small unit $\mathrm{d}x$ of change, with respect to which all the other changes are measured. For example,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} \approx \frac{f(x+\mathrm{d}x) - f(x)}{\mathrm{d}x} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \approx \sum_{a + k\mathrm{d}x \in [a, b]} f(a+k\mathrm{d}x) \, \mathrm{d}x, $$
etc.

$\delta(x)$ is a "function" that assigns a unit mass near $x = 0$. For example, this may be realized as
$$ \delta(x) \approx \begin{cases} \frac{1}{\mathrm{d}x}, & |x| < \mathrm{d}x / 2, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases} $$
Then we may argue that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\approx \sum_{k} f(k\mathrm{d}x) \, \delta(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\approx f(0). $$



I appreciate the reply!

The Dirac delta "function" isn't a function, and the things you write in your question do not make literal sense.  Instead, it is an abuse of notation that has a certain plausibility to it, but which most people who use it don't understand.  The actual picture is this:
We have a natural pairing between (nice function), $\langle f,g\rangle =\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)g(x)dx$, and if $f$ is continuous and $g$ is only non-zero on a very small interval around $0$, then because continuous functions don't vary a lot on very small intervals, $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)g(x)dx\approx f(0)\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)dx$  As the support of $g$ gets smaller and smaller, the approximation becomes better and better.
So, for example, we could set
$$g_n=\begin{cases}2n \quad & \text{if }x\in(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n})\\ 0 \quad &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle f,g_n\rangle=f(0)$ whenever $f$ is continuous.  But there is no literal function that the $g(x)$ converge to, and even if it did, we wouldn't necessarily have that the integral commutes with the limit.  But we do have that as an operator on continuous functions, the pairings are approaching the operator that sends $f(x)$ to $f(0)$.  So we say "wouldn't it be nice if there were a function that we were integrating against to make this happen?" And then we call that non-existent function $\delta(x)$.

Since you pulled out f(0) from the integral, couldn't you in theory do that with g(x) too?

@TheMathPotato That relied on $f(x)$ being very close to $f(0)$ when $x$ is small, together with $g(x)$ being $0$ when $x$ isn't small.  We aren't making the assumption that $f(x)$ is zero outside of a very small range, so the setup isn't symmetric.

I see, that makes more sense, thank you.
